# Setting JAVA_HOME on Ubuntu 10.x

Tags: ubuntu, java, path

I'm trying to get the Rhodes framework installed so I can develop Android apps.

This requires that I install the SUN JDK and add JAVA_HOME and JAVA_HOME/bin to path.

I thought I could solve this by editing my bash.bashrc file:

> JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java"
>   export JAVA_HOME
>   PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

This still doesn't work, because when I run:

> rake run:android

I get a prompt in the console that says the Java bin was not found in my path.

However, running echo $PATH gets me:

> usernamee@ubuntu:~$ echo $PATH
>   /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/username/ruby/gems/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java/bin:/home/username/ruby_files/android-sdk-linux_86/tools

What are my options here?

Edit: If the problem is not the export statement, how can I ensure that the Sun JDK is properly installed and that I am, in fact, pointing to the correct path in bashrc?

Comment: run `echo $JAVA_HOME` in a terminal. What does that give you? Also, lose the "export" statement, should be unnecessary and might be what's giving you the problem.

Comment: username@ubuntu:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the export statement:

```
JAVA_HOME = /path/to/java
PATH = $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Then echo $JAVA_HOME in a *new* terminal to make sure you've got things exported correctly.

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

---

Alternatively, try this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Comment: username@ubuntu:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java

Comment: Did you edit your .bashrc file? Did it work?

Comment: Yes, I took out the export statement, then opened a new shell. Still same problem.

Comment: Try new above edits.

Comment: Same problem. I think the issue is tied to my java installation. Should I delete everything from my jvm folder, then start from scratch?

Comment: How did you install Java? And you're using Sun JDK? If so, why? You should wipe your Java install if you're using Sun/Oracle/Corporate/Whatever JVM, then run `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk`.

Comment: Why should I use the openjdk as opposed to sun?

Comment: Better support, easier install. I've never had any problems or real differences in using OpenJDK and Sun, in fact I've heard that OpenJDK performs better as a server than the Sun JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on Ubuntu, and it seems that you are using the default packages of Sun's Java for the OS, you should probably use the `update-alternatives' command. As you can see, I have 2 JVM's installed, but the Sun version is the one that gets used by default.

```
root@workstation:~# update-alternatives --query java
Link: java
Status: manual
Best: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java
Value: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java

Alternative: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java
Priority: 1061
Slaves:
 java.1.gz /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/man/man1/java.1.gz

Alternative: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java
Priority: 63
Slaves:
 java.1.gz /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

If you only have one, you don't have to worry about it. If you have more than one, and need to set it, you can use the Java-specific version of the command, `update-java-alternatives'. It's all here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Comment: And, now that I think about it, shouldn't this go to the "Ask Ubuntu" StackExchange site?